# Project reference trying to find platform specific dll when it's an agnostic library

Tags: c#, msbuild, maui

I have a multi-platform MAUI solution with several projects in it. One of the project references needs to change with the platform, so I moved it from the .sln file (where the GUI put it) and into the project file as a conditioned element:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference
      Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) != 'android'"
      Include="..\NonAndroidLibrary\NonAndroidLibrary.csproj"
    >
    <Project>{8cd7a9a7-9740-4f03-83bc-4ae8f09cdcb9}</Project>
    <Name>NonAndroidLibrary</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
...
</ItemGroup>
```

The library project just targets .net7.0, but I'm getting errors because platform specific binaries cannot be found:

```ini
Error   WMC1006 Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'M:\repos\MainSolution\NonAndroidLibrary\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\NonAndroidLibrary.dll'   MainProject M:\repos\MainSolution\MainProject\MainProject.csproj    1   
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'M:\repos\MainSolution\NonAndroidLibrary\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\NonAndroidLibrary.dll' could not be found   MainProject (net7.0-android)    M:\repos\MainSolution\MainProject\CSC   1   Active
```

The second error (CS0006) is duplicated for the other platforms, but the WMC1006 is currently only displayed for Windows.

Another `.net7.0` project (still referenced in the .sln) is not causing this problem and the single output dll in `debug\.net7.0\` is being brought in correctly.

What do I need to do to bring in a platform agnostic dll to a multi-targeting app in the `.csproj`?

Comment: Which project file is the above one? The `Name` tag suggests you added the conditional reference to `NonAndroidLibrary.csproj` _into_ that same file. You should put that conditional reference into the file consuming the library.

Comment: Yes, that's the consuming project, the one that actually builds the app. Sorry if that wasn't clear. The `<Name>` was in the example I copied from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an element that can be placed within `<ProjectReference>` tags that tells the build engine what sort of project to expect:

```
<SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=net7.0</SetTargetFramework>
```

Putting this in the snippet above solves the problem.

This element seems not to be suggested by Intellisense within VS2022, but it is referenced in a couple of places, such as: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3243

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.